# Rounding to 2 decimal places c#

Tags: c#, rounding

Currently have a working rounding model within my c# code and is perfectly rounding numbers that have more than 2 decimal places down to 2 decimal places which is great. However, when i have lets say `double value = 100.6`, and i put that into `double dollar_value = Math.Round(value, 2)`, it still returns as 100.6.

I was wondering if there was a way to transform a 1 decimal place value to 2 decimal places?

Comment: `ToString("N2")` or simply `ToString("N")`

Comment: actually you can use that as a rounding-model as well: `Double d = Double.Parse(unrounded.ToString("#,##0.00"));` :-)

Answer (score 3):

Numbers are not stored with extra zeroes (As it is a waste of memory to do so, being the numbers are the same with or without). In order to represent a number this way you will either need to display or store it as a string.

```
string str = value.ToString("#.00", CultureInfo.InvariantCulture);
```

Now `str` will always have 2 decimal places.

Comment: yeah i came across this method, but it is kind of hard to transform the current data we use at the moment into a string. But it's not a major issue as it still reads the data properly, just needed it for display purposes.

Comment: Specifically 100.6 and 100.60 are the same number

Comment: @AnujHari Your comment makes no sense. You don't need to store it as a string; just convert it to string when you display it.

Answer (score 1):

I don't know the C# method, but in C++ I'd use one of these two methods:

```
double value = 23.666666 ; // example
value = 0.01 * floor ( value * 100.0 ) ; // There's a "floor" function in C# too
```

^ See https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/e0b5f0xb(v=vs.110).aspx

Or

```
double value = 23.666666 ; // example
value = 0.01 * (double) ( (int)(value*100.0) ) ;
```

Or

```
double value = 23.666666 ; // example
value = 0.01 * double ( int ( value*100.0 ) ) ; // same as previous, but more C++ like
```

The other answers are probably better if you're looking to "print a dollar amount with two decimal places." However, if you want to transform the number to use internally, this is a way to do it.

Comment: The only actual answer to the question is downvoted ... So sad

Answer (score 0):

If you want the string representation to have two decimal points use:
`yourNumber.ToString ("0.00");`

The number itself is always stored as a ~29 digit number regardless of its string representation.

Comment: `InvariantCulture` should be used or else you will run into issues in other areas/languages with other characters such as commas are used as a separator.

Answer (score 0):

Your value just needs to be formatted when it's display - for example `value.ToString("N2")` will convert it to a string with two decimal places. Check out the [Standard Numeric Format Strings](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dwhawy9k(v=vs.110).aspx) on MSDN to see a broader list of formatting strings.

Additionally, I'd only convert to a string when you're ready display the value to a user and would keep it as a numeric type (e.g. double) if you're passing it around between methods or planning to do any further calculations on it. Otherwise you'll be unnecessarily converting the value to and from a string multiple times.

Comment: Note that using `N` will insert a comma separator (`3,000.00`) as well, which may or may not be what is needed.

Comment: Good point, thanks @Cyral - perhaps `"F2"` would be a better fit.